# How can you click on an element by multiple text matches?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have some cards that have various fields. And the text looks something like this.

Terrier

Age 2

Name Rex

Location Colorado

I need to match a single card by multiple texts. So `element(by.cssContainingText('#age', 'Age 2'))` is not very helpful because I also need '#location' to match 'Colorado'.

What I tried is chaining `element.all(by.cssContainingText('#card','Age')).element.all(by.cssContainingText('#location', 'Colorado'))` but it doesn't seem to work and it is very messy.
The end goal is to click on the first card that matches.

I also tried creating a function that matches the texts. However if there is more than one match after the first click, it will also try to click the next one and I will get a stale element error.

```
public clickDogCardByAgeAndLocation(age: string, location: string) {
      common.waitForElement($('dog-card'));
      $$('dog-card').each(element => {
        element.getText().then(text => {
          if (text.includes(age) && text.includes(location)) {
            console.log('CARD SUCCESS');
            element.click();
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your text is on one element, you can use xpath to find multiple conditions like this:

```
//p[contains(text(),'I am')][contains(text(),'more elegant')][contains(text(),'do this')]
```

That, for example, matches your last line:
[image: xpath for multiples]

If your text is across multiple child elements you can select the parent card by wrapping that identifier like this:

```
//div[p[contains(text(),'I am')][contains(text(),'more elegant')][contains(text(),'do this')]]
```

that's the `div` that contains the `p` that contains those text conditions.

There are also xpath modifiers that make it easier to read such and and or:

```
//p[contains(text(),'I am') and contains(text(),'more elegant')]
```

You can try all of these on this page :-)

If you have a more complex object, please share your html and i can help with something more bespoke.

Comment: Thanks, this solution looks much better. I am also considering regex, so I can do something like ```element(by.cssContainingText('#parent-card', /regex matching age AND location/))```. I would only use xpath if there was no other way.

Comment: Intsead of regex, if you still need it - you can do css and substring match with  `attribute*`  -  for example, throw this into devtools (on this page) `a[name*='b-t'][name*='top']`   - this page has an element `<a name="tab-top">` and it matches this with partials  (overlapping partials nonetheless)